# How can I access the values in a set from any screen in an app?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

When my app starts, it iterates through a list of words and creates a particular set. This set is created right when the app starts. Once it is created, it will no longer change.
How can I access this set from any screen?
Do I have to use provider? Should I pass this set from screen to screen down the widget tree?
Or as it is in a way a "constant set" (it will not change, once it is created), there is another way to make it accessible from everywhere in the app?

Comment: Add your code. With your code here, it is easier to help you.

Answer (score -1):

It depends. If your App only has 2 or 3 screens, you can pass the data from screen to screen. If you have more screens, I would recommend InheritedWidget:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

It is not the only way to do it, but it is what I generally use.

Your InheritedWidget should look like this (this code was not tested)

```
class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget
 {
  final allValues;


    MyInheritedWidget(
     {
       Key? key,
       required this.allValues,
       required Widget child
      }): super(key: key, child: child);


  static MyInheritedWidget? of(BuildContext context)
   {
   return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>();
   }
 }
```

You can then you it in your main():

```
void main() {
 ///You can generate your values here
 final theValues = generateYourValues();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => MyInheritedWidget
        (
          allValues: theValues,
          child: AppStarter()
        ),

        '/message': (context) => AnotherPage(),
       },
    ),
  );
 }
```

Comment: What if I store it in sharepreferences ? can I easily retrieve it ?

Comment: You can also do that if you are just saving a couple of values. I don't know if it is easier. It depends on you.
Personally, I put my Inherited Widget at the beginning of my App and I can access data from everywhere in my App. I just have to call the Widget.

Comment: OK I will look into inHerited Widgets. I have no idea how they work ;) Isn't it what Provider is based on ?

Comment: Thank you for your help above. Still a bit hard for me to follow. But I am working on it.

Comment: You should add a code. Without your code, it is hard to know what you have already done

Comment: So far, I haven't tackled the problem yet. I wanted to know in which direction I should go. so Far, I generate the list in the screen where it is needed. But that means, it will call this method each time it opens a screen where it is needed, which is kinda stupid as this list will not change once generated.

Comment: Where is your code? You need help but you don't show your code and you don't want to use the solution I am trying to explain you. What do you want at the end?
The list can be generated when the app is starting and you don't have to generate it later again. You just have to call the same list saved in the Inherited Widget.

Comment: Yes I will look into the inHerited Widget in depth.

Comment: I wanted to reach to you in the chat. But I have lost some reputation points apparently. So am not allowed.